# Windows - How to copy one file from each sub-folder (Sampling)

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, directory

I know how to do it Java, simply open each folder and copy the first file and then next folder and so on.

What I want to know if it is possible with to do this a batch file? (e.g. `for` loop)

To clarify again, let say I have a folder of 1000 sub-folders and each folder includes many files (with the same format and different names). I want to copy a sample file of each folder in a destination folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /d %%a in (*) do (
    SET "folder=%%~a"
    FOR %%b IN ("%%~a\*") DO SET "file=%%~b"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    COPY "!file!" "X:\target folder"
    ENDLOCAL
)
```

Comment: I guess it copies all the files.  But I want a sample from each folder. I don't understand what should I put as my file name, where I don't know my file name

Comment: Sorry :( but I also don't know your filenames. How should the file be selected?

Comment: That's the main part of the question. I just want a random (or first) file of the folder, not a specific one.

Comment: It works for me with some edits. Did you check it or just write it by heart? I can edit your answer in the way that works for me if you don't mind